# Running time scales with the number of threads when running a function received from Python inside OpenMP parallel block

Tags: openmp, pybind11

Here are the files for test.

```
# CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(CALLBACK_TEST)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_compile_options(-O3 -fopenmp -fPIC)
add_link_options(-fopenmp)

add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(callback callback.cpp)

add_custom_command(TARGET callback POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink $<TARGET_FILE:callback> ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/callback.so
)
```

```cpp
// callback.cpp

#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

class C
{
public:
  C(std::function<float(float)> f, size_t s) : f_(f), v_(s, 1) {}
  void apply()
  {
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v_.size(); i++)
      v_[i] = f_(v_[i]);
  }
  void apply_direct()
  {
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v_.size(); i++)
      v_[i] = log(1 + v_[i]);
  }

private:
  std::vector<float> v_;
  std::function<float(float)> f_;
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(callback, m)
{
  py::class_<C>(m, "C")
      .def(py::init<std::function<float(float)>, size_t>())
      .def("apply", &C::apply, py::call_guard<py::gil_scoped_release>())
      .def("apply_direct", &C::apply_direct);
  m.def("log1p", [](float x) -> float
        { return log(1 + x); });
}
```

```py
# callback.py

import math
import time

from callback import C, log1p


def run(n, func):
    start = time.time()
    if func:
        for _ in range(n):
            c = C(func, 1000)
            c.apply()
    else:
        for _ in range(n):
            c = C(func, 1000)
            c.apply_direct()
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 1000
    one = 1
    print("Python")
    run(n, lambda x: math.log(x + 1))
    print("C++")
    run(n, log1p)
    print("Direct")
    run(n, None)
```

I run the Python script on a server with 48 CPU cores. Here is the running time. It shows 1. the running time increases when `OMP_NUM_THREADS` increases especially when accepting the Python/C++ callback from Python, and 2. keeping everything inside C++ is much faster, which seems to contradict the "no overhead" claim as in the [documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/functional.html).

```
$ python callback.py
Python
19.612852573394775
C++
19.268250226974487
Direct
0.04382634162902832
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 python callback.py
Python
6.042902708053589
C++
5.48648738861084
Direct
0.03322458267211914
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 python callback.py
Python
0.5964927673339844
C++
0.38849639892578125
Direct
0.020793914794921875
```

And when OpenMP is turned off:

```
$ python callback.py
Python
0.8492450714111328
C++
0.26660943031311035
Direct
0.010872125625610352
```

So what goes wrong here?

Comment: OpenMP has overheads, so in such a very small calculation it is not worth using it in C++.  I have no experience in mixing C++ and python, so I cannot comment those results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

First of all, the OpenMP parallel region should have a significant overhead here since it needs to share the work between 48 threads. This work-sharing can be quite expensive on some platform regarding the scheduling policy. You need to use `schedule(static)` to minimize this overhead. In the worst case, a runtime could create 48 threads and join them every time which is expensive. Creating/Joining 48*1000 threads would be very expensive (it should take at least several seconds). The higher the number of thread, the slower the program. That being said, most runtimes try to keep an active pool of threads. Still, this is not always possible (and this is an optimization, not required by the specification). Note that most OpenMP runtimes detect the case where `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is set to 1 so to have a very low overhead in this case. The general rule of thumb is to **avoid using multithreading for very short operations** like one taking less than 1 ms.

Moreover, the parallel for loop is subject to **false sharing**. Indeed, the vector of 1000 float items will take 4000 bytes in memory and it will be spread in 63 cache lines of 64 bytes on mainstream platforms. With 48 threads, almost all cache lines have to move between cores which is expensive compared to the computation done. When two threads working on adjacent cache line have an interleaved execution, a cache line can bounce many times for just few iteration. On NUMA architecture, this is even more expensive since cache lines have to move between NUMA nodes. Doing this 1000 times is very expensive.

Additionally, AFAIK calling a python function from a parallel context is either not safe, or is subject to no speed-up because of the **global interpreter lock** (GIL). By not safe, I mean that the CPython interpreter data structure can be corrupted causing non-deterministic crashes. This is why the GIL exists. The GIL prevent all code to scale on multiple thread as long as it is not released. Releasing a GIL for a too short period also cause cache line bouncing which is detrimental for performance (more than using a sequential code).

Finally, the "C++" and Python have a much bigger overhead than the "direct" method because they are calling **dynamically-defined functions that cannot be inlined or vectorized by the compiler**. Python functions are especially slow because of the CPython *interpreter*. If you want to make a fair benchmark you need to compare the PyBind solution with one that use `std::function` (be careful about clever compiler optimizations though).

Comment: Isn't the default scheduling friendly to caching already? With the default scheduling, thread 1 cares about elements 0--20, thread 2 cares about 21--42 etc. They are accessing a continuous part of the data. For the GIL, it has been released when creating the binding, i.e., by the extra `py::call_guard<py::gil_scoped_release>()` argument.

Comment: The default strategy is automatically chosen by the compiler. It may or may not be the static one (it is often static). In your case, using a static partitioning is mandatory for performance so setting it is better. Using a scheduling of blocks of 16 floats should give you better result as long as the array is aligned in memory. But honestly, the computation is far too small for so many thread. You can speed this up using SIMD instructions instead. For the GIL, indeed, but you should check is the GIL is release once or many times. The later is very inefficient and tends to serialize threads.